# Discord.app macOS Catalina 10.15.4 (19E287) would like to receive keystrokes from any application. Should I trust

Tags: macos

I'm assuming this is a new "feature" of macOS Catalina 10.15.4?  My guess is it is safe to allow but for now I am going to Deny.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend denying it and seeing if the application works correctly. If not, then you might want to allow it. Keystroke settings can be changed in Security Preferences > Privacy > Input Monitoring.

Comment: It's probably using that feature to allow you to access the overlay while in a game.

Answer (score 2):

On June 17, 2020, Reddit's [r/discordapp](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/haygfd/why_is_discord_asking_permission_to_record_all_of/) explained:

> We require accessibility permissions for systemwide push-to-talk to work. If you disable this permission, Discord will still function just fine, you’ll just need to open the app for your PTT hot key to function.